# What's disadvantages of array(s) inside another array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose that I have this  line of code:

```
 Object [] b = {3,new int[]{12,34,34},new int[][]{{1,2},{2,3}}};
```

My questions are :

- Why I don't see such a thing used by programmers what's problem with it and dose java have another better way to implement this?.
- How to get all values including(arrays& matrices)?
- How The memory gives the location to Matrix inside the array ?

  I will be thankful if you show me a real example.

Comment: Mixing different types in an array is a terrible thing to do and leads to a very brittle program. Just don't do it, end of story.

Comment: I'm not sure that will even compile...

Comment: I guess it would compile if it were an `Object[]`, but regardless, this is bad news.

Comment: If you must mix data types (bad idea), Java has the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) base class.

Comment: Before you could use any item from array you would have to check its type. This ruins entire purpose of array type. Of course you can do it, but have mercy on others who will have to maintain your code.

Comment: I don't care the down votes just I wanna get the idea .
Thanks @OliCharlesworth & Hovercraft I change it to Object

Comment: @AzadOmer: the idea is this: ***don't do this***. Do you get it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am not doing it I am just supposing.

Comment: Well don't suppose, don't consider, don't implement. This is something that would be a maintenance nightmare. Voting to close this question.

Comment: The solution, if you need to mix types is to create a class to hold the different types, not to create a pseudo-class with an array.

Comment: Thanks all for the useful advises and please don't  delete this post maybe someone else asks the same question and makes all of you suffering from a head ache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The snippet (as it stood originally) is (was) illegal because an array of ints can contain *only* ints, not arrays of ints.

If you declare `b` as an array of *Objects* the code is legal. You don't tend to see code like this in programs because mixing different types of objects in a container is rarely useful (most often you want a collection of a particular type of object) and potentially dangerous (you cannot use the compiler to guarantee that you don't accidentally put something unintended into the array).

**How to get all values?**

You can use a recursive method that uses reflection or the `instanceof` operator to check if the current element is an array.

**How The memory gives the location to Matrix inside the array ?**

Java has no matrices, only arrays that contain pointers to other arrays.